# Preventing cyclic Parent/Child data when using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list

Given a data model which contains reference to its parent (adjacency list):

```
class Foo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   virtual Foo Parent { get; set; }
}
```

How can I guarantee that no cyclic references will be committed to the database?

ok:

```
a
  b
    c
```

NOT ok:

```
a
  b
    c
      a
```

Is this something I can do by setting the isolation level (to Serializable)? Is this best done using some sort of trigger in the database itself? Should I be using a different model for my hierarchical data?

Comment: "Is this something I can do by setting the isolation level (to Serializable)?" - transaction isolation levels are more concerned with _low-level_ inconsistent reads rather than violations of custom `CHECK` constraints.

Comment: "Is this best done using some sort of trigger in the database itself?" - you should avoid triggers on tables entirely because they break `OUTPUT` clauses, not to mention are a massive pain to work with because they aren't declarative: instead use a `CHECK` constraint with a custom UDF for non-trivial constraint expressions - but be aware of the performance implications of using queries in UDFs in CHECK constraints (note that my advice to generally avoid triggers does _not_ apply to triggers on `VIEW` objects though).

Comment: "Given a data model which contains reference to its parent (adjacency list)" - the `class Foo` you've posted does not demonstrate an adjacency-list and you haven't defined your key columns  - so I have no idea how EF would convert that into a `CREATE TABLE` statement - but anyway: while EF and EF Core do support schema-migrations and creating a database design from C# class definitions, it's still nowhere near as flexible and expressive as doing database design manually, which means if I were in your situation this question is moot because I wouldn't be depending on EF to create constraints.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for your comments, I've added a Key property to the DataModel in the question. So if transaction isolations levels don't work, and I should avoid triggers, and UDFs have performance implications and you wouldn't use EFCore to create constraints, how WOULD you deal with this situation? Would you use a different Datamodel (Nested Set?)? Some sort of locking system and then parent/child analysis in code? Use raw SQL queries which only allow an update if the parent/child relationship is valid?

Comment: You could save changes in a transaction, then execute a recursive query (CTE) to validate the final set of database records, rolling back on error. As a final test to ensure multiple users cant change different records and create a loop.

Comment: Of course you couldn't insert the data like that in one transaction (irrespective of isolation level), but nothing keeps you from adding a reference a -> c later. To prevent that you have to build a check yourself. There's nothing in EF or triggers that offers that out of the box.

Comment: @ClaudeHasler "how WOULD you deal with this situation?" - I'd define the database design in SSDT using SQL Server Graph Tables instead, and define `VIEW` objects to project an EF-friendly view of the graph data and then use [EF POCO](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) to generate EF types _from_ the database, not the other way around - and in fact, I'd completely disable EF migrations entirely because I simply don't trust EF to trash my database otherwise. (Disclaimer: I'm a contributor towards EF POCO).

Comment: @ClaudeHasler I just realised we never actually asked you what your graph actually is or what is represents. If this is meant to be an acyclic hiearchy then you can sidestep this problem entirely by just using [SQL Server's `heirarchyid` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/tutorial-using-the-hierarchyid-data-type) which makes it easy to prevent cycles forming - also, the _adjacency list_ representation of graphs _really_ doesn't work in RDBMS, see here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14388/10044

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think it is enough to put the following in the "Parent" class:

```
    [JsonIgnore] //if you will ever Serialize it
    [ForeignKey("OrderProductionNumber")] //using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    public virtual Foo Parent { get; set; }
```